# Pull Single Item From Array

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to pull the information stored in `$Win32_LogicalDisk` for the system drive which is pulled from the `$Win32_OperatingSystem.SystemDrive` variable.

```
$Temp_SystemDrive = $Win32_logicalDisk |
    Select DeviceID, FreeSpace, Size |
    Where-Object (($_.DeviceID) -like ($Win32_OperatingSystem.SystemDrive));
$Temp_SystemDrive
```

Answer (score 3):

`Win32_LogicalDisk` and `Win32_OperatingSystem` are not variables, they are WMI-classes. You need to use `Get-WmiObject` to access them. Try this:

```
#Save OS-information early to clean up your code
$os = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem)

#Save the ORIGINAL object for disk in the case you need more info later
$Temp_SystemDrive = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk | Where-Object { $_.DeviceID -eq $os.SystemDrive }

#Get the properties you need
$Temp_SystemDrive | Select DeviceID, FreeSpace, Size
```

Comment: `Get-WmiObject` can do the filtering by itself: `Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='$($os.SystemDrive)'"`

Answer (score 1):

To get best performance, only pull the fields you need, and apply filter at the query level, not after:

```
$os = Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT SystemDrive FROM Win32_OperatingSystem"
$wmiQuery = "SELECT DeviceID, FreeSpace, Size " + 
              "FROM Win32_LogicalDisk " +
             "WHERE DeviceID='$($os.SystemDrive)'"
Get-WmiObject -Query $wmiQuery
```